# Redisson, working queue / dequeu. Strategies on processing message / element on incomplete message handling on system / pod shutdown

Tags: java, redis, redisson

So I **takeHead** then i start processing. Problem if this is to be scaled and using an 8 thread executor service per pod/instance, on sudden shutdown of system, the "messages" would have been deemed taken / consumed already.

One strategy I guess is to use a separate **distributed** Redisson **list** / map per queue / dequeue that says that these elements / messages are being processed. I guess that would work, however keeping track of that list is not easy either.

Is there a way to takeHead, use live object somehow and then mark an element in queue as being managed, and then somehow remove it when done O(1) ?

Answer (score 1):

> So I takeHead then i start processing. Problem if this is to be scaled and using an 8 thread executor service per pod/instance, on sudden shutdown of system, the "messages" would have been deemed taken / consumed already.

You need to use RStream object instead it allows to track unconsumed elements per consumer.

Comment: Ah, that is the new Redis 5 stuff you mentioned on the kafka question. I need to look into that a bit more. I've however come quite a way with my queue backed by map containing system id to list "processing messages" approach. Almost solid. But will take a look at the RStream approach.

Comment: How come the RStream add expects a key and a value. The Queue approach would only require adding. What is the key required for? Maybe an RStream based Queue should be provided? Documentation is not great as of now, as I believe it is kind of freshly written, so kind of hard to figure out.

Comment: So the ack marks something added as processed, does it delete it as well. When we readgroup, does multiple consumers get the same message to be processed, or only one consumer? How can I ensure that no more than one processes a message?

Comment: StreamMessageId.NEVER_DELIVERED will ensure it only gets to one ?

Comment: stream.readGroup("specialgroup", "consumer1", 1) will ensure I only get one message at a time? If i get too many, and nuclear occurs before processing success of message, they will be marked delivered but not processed, but there is no StreamMessagId.REPRESENTING_THAT_CASE. Will these end up on the NEVER_DELIVERED stack eventually on timeout devoid of an ack? What is the timeout for that?

Comment: Also, the keys for stream.add is effectively the same given the desire to mimic a queue, correct? it is a one key named stream, where key = name basically